# Meio upload behavior - zoom crop not working

Tags: cakephp, upload, thumbnails

I'm using this MeioUpload Behavior. And i installed both phpThumb component and phpThumb vendor.

Thumbnail generation is working fine but zoom-cropping is not.
Here is my code. You can see i've tried every possible variables. I also set every default zc or zoom_crop variables I found in component and vendor to 1. 1 is the same as C anyway.

```
var $actsAs = array('MeioUpload' => array(  'filename' => array(
   'dir' => "uploads/images",
   'create_directory' => true,
   'allowed_mime' => array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png'),
   'allowed_ext' => array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif'),
   'thumbsizes' => array(
       'small'  => array('width'=>65, 'height'=>60,'zc'=>"C", 'zoomCrop' => "C", 'zoom_crop'=>"C"),
       'medium' => array('width'=>159, 'height'=>130, 'zc'=>"C", 'zoomCrop' => "C", 'zoom_crop'=>"C"),
       'large'  => array('width'=>480, 'height'=>320,'zc'=>"C",  'zoomCrop' => "C", 'zoom_crop'=>"C")
   )
  )
   )
 );
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in latest version is necessary to define thumbnail precisely. I'm not sure if this solve your problem with script in older version.

```
var $actsAs = array(
'MeioUpload' => array(
  'img_file' => array(        
    'create_directory' => true,
    'allowed_mime' => array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png'),
    'allowed_ext' => array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'),
    'zoomCrop' => true,
    'thumbsizes' => array(
      'normal' => array('width' => 400, 'height' => 300),
      'small' => array('width' => 80, 'height' => 80,'maxDimension' => '', 'thumbnailQuality' => 100, 'zoomCrop' => true),
    ),
    'default' => 'default.jpg'
  ) 
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I gave up the use of MeioUpload to generate-and-save thumbnails.
Instead, I generate thumbnails on-the-fly, directly using phpThumb.
Like this

```
<img src="<?=$this->webroot?>phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=../uploads/images/<?=$event['Image'][0]['filename']?>&w=159&h=130&zc=1" alt="Event Picture">
```

It's a little sacrifice for performance but every easy and flexible.